# How to use SMO ServerConnection and Database with a contained user in Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure-sql-database, smo

Is there way to use SMO for user who have no access to `master`?

I am scripting out the DLL of an Azure SQL Database via SMO. I used a contained user with db_owner role to access the db and DDL but it throws exception. SMO as soon as I create ServerConnection attempts to default to `master` from which this contained user have no permission.

I used the latest SMO version released on nuget and code in .NET Core 3.0.

```sql
--exec in master db
CREATE LOGIN testuser WITH PASSWORD='...';

--exec in user db: testsqldb
CREATE USER testuser FROM LOGIN testuser
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER testuser
```

The connection string has `InitialCatalog = testsqldb`

```cs
var connectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(sourceConnectionString);
var serverConnection = CreateServerConnection(_connectionString);

//this throws exception
var server = new Server(serverConnection);
```

Exception details

```cs
{"The server principal \"testuser\" is not able to access the database \"master\" under the current security context.\r\nCannot open user default database. Login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'testuser'."}
```

I expect the ServerConnection to respect the InitialCatalog specified in the ConnectionString and not default to 'master'

Answer (score 2):

I've tested the following code working against SQL Azure:

```
ServerConnection conn = new ServerConnection(instanceUrl, username, password);
conn.DatabaseName = database;
_sqlServer = new Server(conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please reference this official SMO tutorial: [Connecting to an Instance of SQL Server by Using SQL Server Authentication in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/create-program/connecting-to-an-instance-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#connecting-to-an-instance-of-sql-server-by-using-sql-server-authentication-in-visual-basic).

When you connect to an instance of SQL Server by using SQL Server Authentication, you must specify the authentication type. This example demonstrates the alternative method of declaring a ServerConnection object variable, which enables the connection information to be reused.

The example is Visual Basic .NET code that demonstrates how to connect to the remote and vPassword contain the logon and password.

```
' compile with:   
' /r:Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll  
' /r:Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll  
' /r:Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll   

Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo  
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common  

Public Class A  
   Public Shared Sub Main()  
      Dim sqlServerLogin As [String] = "user_id"  
      Dim password As [String] = "pwd"  
      Dim instanceName As [String] = "instance_name"  
      Dim remoteSvrName As [String] = "remote_server_name"  

      ' Connecting to an instance of SQL Server using SQL Server Authentication  
      Dim srv1 As New Server()   ' connects to default instance  
      srv1.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = False   ' set to true for Windows Authentication  
      srv1.ConnectionContext.Login = sqlServerLogin  
      srv1.ConnectionContext.Password = password  
      Console.WriteLine(srv1.Information.Version)   ' connection is established  

      ' Connecting to a named instance of SQL Server with SQL Server Authentication using ServerConnection  
      Dim srvConn As New ServerConnection()  
      srvConn.ServerInstance = ".\" & instanceName   ' connects to named instance  
      srvConn.LoginSecure = False   ' set to true for Windows Authentication  
      srvConn.Login = sqlServerLogin  
      srvConn.Password = password  
      Dim srv2 As New Server(srvConn)  
      Console.WriteLine(srv2.Information.Version)   ' connection is established  

      ' For remote connection, remote server name / ServerInstance needs to be specified  
      Dim srvConn2 As New ServerConnection(remoteSvrName)  
      srvConn2.LoginSecure = False  
      srvConn2.Login = sqlServerLogin  
      srvConn2.Password = password  
      Dim srv3 As New Server(srvConn2)  
      Console.WriteLine(srv3.Information.Version)   ' connection is established  
   End Sub  
End Class
```

You can connect to `testsqldb` with your new login/user `testuser`  by change the with SMO.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the issue seems to be connected to behaviour of SMO when connecting to Az SQL Databases. Similar cases here, it automatically switches to master when I tried to capture the source database.

server = new Server(connection);
//server auto switch to master after this line
database = server.Databases[connectionStringBuilder.InitialCatalog];
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798187/failure-to-create-table-in-sql-azure-database-using-smo

Comment: Thanks, @rdagumampan. Did you solved it by reference this blog ?